Stream compressed chunks of data to SFTP server
I'm loading batches of data from database and need to save them to a remote SFTP server using Java into a single bzip2 compressed file. I'm using JSch SFTP client. Is there any possibility to compress each batch (chunk) of data on the fly and concatenate to a resulting file? Or is it possible to use BufferedInputStream and to compress the buffer on every iteration and pass it to put(InputStream src, String dst) method of JSch? I don't want to store all the data in memory or local file because of its size. Is it possible with bzip2 format?

Use one of the ChannelSftp.put overloads that return OutputStream:
https://epaul.github.io/jsch-documentation/javadoc/com/jcraft/jsch/ChannelSftp.html#put-java.lang.String-
And write the bzip data to the stream as you create it.

Or pipe bzip OutputStream to an InputStream that you pass to JSch:
How do I convert an OutputStream to an InputStream?

My final solution is:
try (OutputStream outputStream = sftpChannel.put("/path/file.bz2"); // creating remote file
     BZip2CompressorOutputStream bzip2OutputStream = new BZip2CompressorOutputStream(outputStream); // bzip2 compression
     InputStream databaseDataInputStream = new DatabaseDataInputStreamImpl(); // my custom implementation for selecting byte data from database into InputStream
     BufferedInputStream databaseStream = new BufferedInputStream(databaseDataInputStream, bufferSize)) {

    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int bytesRead;
    while ((bytesRead = databaseStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        bzip2OutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
    bzip2OutputStream.finish();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // ...
} 

